# How to get a column in excel to reset to zero on the first of each month

Tags: excel

I am building a worksheet that I want to be able to reset column I to 0 on the first of the month. I am storing the date in K196 with the `=NOW()` formula. could someone help me find a code that would work for my situation. I found one on here but do not know how o modify it to support my needs. The formula I found on here is

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    if Sheets("Output").Range("Z4").value > 0 then
        If Month(Sheets("Output").Range("A4")) <> Sheets("Output").Range("Z4") Then
            Range("B4:T4").ClearContents
            Sheets("Output").Range("Z4") = Month(Sheets("Output").Range("A4"))
        End If
    End IF
End Sub
```

Tanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use VBA's [`Day()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b4h8sxy(v=vs.90).aspx) function on *Date* value or *K196* cell. Below uses *Sheet1* as target sheet.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    If Day(Date) = 1 Then
        Sheets(1).Range("I1:I" & lastrow) = 0
    End If

   ' ALTERNATIVELY USING K196 CELL VALUE
    If Day(Sheets(1).Range("K196")) = 1 Then
        Sheets(1).Range("I1:I" & lastrow) = 0
    End If
End Sub
```